# PLSQL: Procedure outputting multiple cursors

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'd like to return multiple cursor in one procedure, one based on other.

My currently code is:

```
TYPE REFCURSOR IS REF CURSOR; 

PROCEDURE GETCARS(oCARS OUT REFCURSOR)
BEGIN
    OPEN oCARS FOR SELECT * FROM CARS;
END GETCARS;
```

I'm not sure if that's posible but I want to make something like:

```
PROCEDURE GETCARS(oCARS OUT REFCURSOR, oREPAIRS OUT REFCURSOR)
BEGIN
    OPEN oCARS FOR SELECT * FROM CARS;
    ..??..
END GETCARS;
```

which would return as a second parameter all repairs connected with currently fetched oCARS row.
(Table repairs has a FK for an id_car from cars)

Now I do that on C# side, when I fetch one row from oCARS cursor I call second procedure which gives me list of repairs, but maybe it's somehow possible to do that in one procedure (which would give me performance gain? - I don't want to use join, cause it returns multiplied cars for each repair)

Comment: why not have 2 procedures (getcars and getrepairs)?  Or better yet, just select what you need when you need it: select * from cars instead of exec getcars()

Comment: Calling plane select is less secure then calling parametrized procedure (sql injection protection).
I THINK that calling 2 procedures is less efficient.. I had hope for some experience of Others here..

Comment: Calling a correctly parameterized select statement is no less secure than calling a procedure. As long as you don't concatenate parameter values into the select statement, there's no vector for SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't do what you are attempting.

Cursors are basically just pointers to the start of the result set that contains the query results. Until you fetch a row, there is no way to know what that row will contain. Because your application, rather than the PL/SQL code, is doing the fetching, the PL/SQL portion has no knowledge of the values being returned.

To do what you're attempting, the database would have to detect the fetch from the first query, create a new result set using the second query, then place the new result set at the address that the procedure originally returned for the second cursor. Databases just aren't designed to handle this kind of operation.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
PROCEDURE GETCARS(oCARS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, oREPAIRS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, oCHARGES OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
BEGIN 
    OPEN oCARS FOR SELECT * FROM CARS; 
    OPEN oREPAIRS FOR SELECT * FROM REPAIRS;
    OPEN oCHARGES FOR SELECT * FROM CHARGES;
END GETCARS;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: It's good, almost good when I want to return all oCars.
But, if I add some extra code, for pagination or date restrictions on some fields, rest cursors would return me more then I need to.

I was hoping for some idea, which would allow me to bind to an id of currently fetched row in oCars and based on that modify returning oRepairs.

Something like:
OPEN oRepairs for select * from repairs where id_car = ocars.id_car

I'm not sure if thats posible.

Comment: @XXs - why don't you spell out *your entire requirement* instead of wasting people's time with this "yes but" schtick?

Comment: learn how to read "which would return as a second parameter all repairs connected with currently fetched oCARS row.". Yes I wanted to improve performance by returning whole DB by cursors.. -.-
A ha, and when I ask question here I ask for extendable solution, not the simplest one.